# Using RabbitMQ with Ruby and Node.js apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using the Bunny gem in Rails and AMQP in Node.js. 
Rails is the publisher and the Node.js app is a subscriber.

Code from Rails:

```
conn = Bunny.new
conn.start

ch = conn.create_channel
x = Bunny::Exchange.new(ch, :direct, "messenger")
q1 = ch.queue("new_messages").bind(x, :routing_key => 'send')
x.publish('hi', :routing_key => 'send')
```

Code from Node.js:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection();

connection.addListener('ready', function(){
    var exchange = connection.exchange('messenger');
    var queue = connection.queue('new_messages')

    queue.bind('messenger', 'send')

    queue.subscribe( {ack:true}, function(message){
        console.log(message.data.toString())
        queue.shift()
    });
});
```

From the management plugin I can see that the Rails code works well, but the code from Node.js doesn't make sense.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is "messanger" (Ruby) / "messenger" (node.js) a typo?

Comment: This isn't really an answer so I'm using a comment, but let me know if it's helpful. There is a MUCH easier way to send messages between Ruby and Node using Redis. The Redis API is much easier to understand, has great clients in Ruby and Node.js, and you can find service providers all over the internet for $5 a month for basic plans. The command you want is rpoplpush http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush. Here's some other help: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis, https://github.com/redis/redis-rb.

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is in how you're attempting to bind your queue to the 'messenger' exchange. You've already used the exchange name to get a reference to the exchange object. Rather than pass in the string name again when binding the queue to the exchange, pass *this reference* into queue.bind(). Simply change the first queue.bind() argument:

```
var exchange = connection.exchange('messenger');    
var queue = connection.queue('new_messages');

// Use the reference to the exchange object you just received;
// pass it in here instead of the exchange's name
queue.bind(exchange, 'send');
```

**EDIT**

Here is a full, working example; just drop in your own connection properties:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({
    host: 'my_host',
    login: 'my_login',
    password: 'my_password',
    authMechanism: 'AMQPLAIN',
    vhost: 'my_vhost'
});

connection.addListener('ready', function(){

    console.log('ready');

    var exchange = connection.exchange('messenger');
    var queue = connection.queue('new_messages');

    queue.bind(exchange, 'send');

    // if message successfully received, print message
    queue.subscribe( {ack:true}, function(message){

        console.log(message.data.toString());
        queue.shift();
    });

    // test by sending a message
    exchange.publish('send', 'this is a test message', {}, function() {})
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Console.log inside subscribe callback shows, that NodeJS can't catch message.

Comment: @Zhirayr, I've updated the example with fully working code, including publishing messages to the queue within the node process. You can use it to confirm my answer above; just drop in your connection properties.